# Android Espresso testing using Kotlin trying to iterate through ChipGroup

Tags: android, testing, kotlin, material-design, android-espresso

My app has `ChipGroup`s with individual `Chip`s inside. [(Documentation)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/ChipGroup) and [(Description)](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/)

What I want to do is to use Espresso libraries in Android to test the functionality of these components. I want to click on the `Chip`s, especially their close buttons, to delete them and check that they were actually removed, etc. I have not been able to find information about iterating over `ChipGroup`s like with using the `foreach`. The methods like `Espresso.onView()` or `.perform()` are missing this functionality. The closest I have come is seeing information on `RecyclerView`s and `ListView`s.

I have looked at the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso) and the [cheatsheet](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/cheat-sheet) among others. Any idea what I ought to do to test these components?

Comment: did you notice that chipGroup is a view group? so i think you can get the children views and iterate it casting each one to checkbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an option:

```
fun chipContainsText(text: String) {
    onView(allOf(withText(containsString(text)), isAssignableFrom(Chip::class.java))).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
}
```

And I use it:

```
chipContainsText(1000)
```

In general, using `isAssignableFrom(CLASS_NAME::class.java)` is always very helpful in difficult situations.

Layout Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The method `isAssignableFrom()` is a powerful statement. The code you gave me worked. When I gave it the text of the `Chip`, the test found and verified it. Thank you! Two enhancements would be great. 1) Allow the text of the `Chip` to be dynamically loaded because the backend sends the string and I don't know it ahead of time. 2) Have more options like clicking the close button on the `Chip`. What have you done to test that?

Comment: Unfortunately or to my joy, I have an element without the possibility of closing (can be seen on the screenshot). 

You can get values for each chip. Or you can click on the element index. 

By the way, I use mock data in this case for checking.  Or I can get the data one step earlier, save it and click on the value that I have saved.